# import data from text file deliminators

Tags: java, delimiter

I'm a little confused with trying to make my program read from a text file. The text file consists of a: Client ID, Client Title, Client Initials, Client Surname, Client address, client town or city, client post code, policy year of issue and policy number. The remaining fields correspond to the type of policy the policy number belongs to. To separate each field I was advised to a DELIMITER.

The text file looks like this:

```
IC-x00042W/Ms/LQ/Bethea/205, Willis Road/Bolton/BO5 1DQ/2007/C02000007/10000/0.5/2008/B27100037/150000/0.3/2011/V30200319/2000/21/1/0#

IC-x00033D/Mr/R/Bowie/119, Thatcher Way/Glasgow/GL9 5SX/2008/L09000016/50000/45/2/2009/C74100008/8000/0.6/2012/B05300001/125000/0.5#

IC-x00013A/MS/GRV/Blackwell/209, Drunk Road/Hawick/HK8 1MY/2013/B09000009/225000/0.1/2011/C14100014/20000/0.1/2010/V63200304/12000/43/5/1#
```

So far I have something that looks like this: (There is a class called Name that contains all the client personal details and a class called address that contains all the address details):

---

```
    final String CLIENT_DELIMITER = "#";
    final String ITEM_DELIMITER = "/";

    Scanner fileScan = null;
    Scanner clientScan = null;

    /*
     * ********************************************************************
     * 
     * Opening the text file and reading from the text file. If the 
     * File cannot be read then an error is thrown
     * 
     * ********************************************************************
     */
    try {
        fileScan = new Scanner(inputFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    //********************************************************************

    String nxtClient = null;


    //Define classes 
    ClientDetailsList clientInfo = null;
    Name clientNameDetails = null;
    Address clientFullAddress = null;
    PolicyList clientPolicies = null;
    ClientDetailsList clientDetails = null;

    ClientDetailsList clientCollection = new ClientDetailsList();

    fileScan.useDelimiter(ITEM_DELIMITER);

    /*
     * ******************************************************************
     * Scan for client details from the text file
     * ******************************************************************
     */

    while (fileScan.hasNext()) {

        // Input the data for the next Client
        nxtClient = fileScan.next().trim();
        clientScan = new Scanner(nxtClient);
        clientScan.useDelimiter(ITEM_DELIMITER);


        //Client Variables
        String clientID = null;
        clientScan.useDelimiter(ITEM_DELIMITER);
        String clientTitle = null;
        String clientInitials = null;
        String clientSurname = null;


        //Reads in details from name
        clientID = fileScan.next().trim();
        clientTitle = fileScan.next().trim();
        clientInitials = fileScan.next().trim();
        clientSurname = fileScan.next().trim();

        //Construct Name
        clientNameDetails = new Name(clientTitle, clientInitials, clientSurname);

        String clientAddress = null;
        String clientTownOrCity = null;
        String clientPostCode = null;
        String policyDetails = null;

        //Reads in details from address
        clientAddress = fileScan.next().trim();
        clientTownOrCity = fileScan.next().trim();
        clientPostCode = fileScan.next().trim();

        //Construct Address
        clientFullAddress = new Address(clientAddress, clientTownOrCity, clientPostCode);
```

Comment: My program is unable to read from the text file. An error occurs when it reaches the ITEM DELIMITER. I'm unsure why this is?

Comment: WHICH error. It has an error message. Read it. or paste it here.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at insurancecodemo.InsuranceCoDemo.readFile(InsuranceCoDemo.java:83)
 at insurancecodemo.InsuranceCoDemo.main(InsuranceCoDemo.java:31)
Java Result: 1                                                                                                                                           The error occurs once it reaches the first DELIMITER

Comment: Is inputFile of type File? It works fine if it is file :)

Comment: OK. Now, which line is the line 83 in InsuranceCoDemo.java?

Comment: Yes, However my program is still unable to read from the file. Its something to do with the delimiters, unable to determine where the next field is.

Comment: line 83 is: fileScan.useDelimiter(ITEM_DELIMITER);

Comment: That means that the line `fileScan = new Scanner(inputFile);` threw an exception before. You shouldn't continue to execute the method if this line throws an exception. You should also print the stack trace of the exception it throws, and read it (or paste it here) to understand what the problem is. The best way to do this is to NOT catch the exception it throws.

Answer (score 0):

```
nxtClient = fileScan.next();
final String[] srcData = nxtClient.split("/");

if (srcData.length != 8){// 8? am i right?
    System.err.println("wrong data line " + nxtClient);
}

for (int i = 0; i < srcData.length; i++){
srcData[i] = srcData[i].trim();
}

 clientNameDetails = new Name(srcData[0], srcData[1], srcData[2]);
.....
```

This one looks more simple, than you solution